# Как выполнить только выделенную часть запроса в DataGrip

Tags: sql, datagrip

Есть много CTE, в которых могут использоваться ранее объявленные CTE. Чтобы по 300 раз не форматировать подобный запрос <cte_name> as ( select ... from ... )  --> select ... from ... Хотелось бы просто выделять часть CTE объявленных ранее и сам запрос внутри рассматриваемой CTE-ки.

пример:
| with
some1 as ( select *
from some_table) |,
some2 as ( | select id, name
from some1 | ),
some3 as ( select id
from some2)

Select * from some3

Логики в запросе нет, просто пример. | - этим символом показываю одновременно выделенные области, которые хотелось бы запустить.